# MySQL "Or" Condition

Tags: php, mysql, select, conditional-statements

Check out this `MySQL` Query and then I'll show you what I really want it to do...

```
mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE
    email='$Email'
    AND date='$Date_Today'
    OR date='$Date_Yesterday'
    OR date='$Date_TwoDaysAgo'
    OR date='$Date_ThreeDaysAgo'
    OR date='$Date_FourDaysAgo'
    OR date='$Date_FiveDaysAgo'
    OR date='$Date_SixDaysAgo'
    OR date='$Date_SevenDaysAgo'");
```

The problem with it is that I want it to always match the email. In this case (for example) if the date equals `$Date_SixDaysAgo` then it will be selected from the query even if `$Email` doesn't equal the email column.

So, in short, I want the email to always equal the email column, and if the query pulls a date that equals `$Daye_TwoDaysAgo` or `$Date_ThreeDaysAgo` etc.. but doesn't equal the email then don't pull it.

I guess my query would look kind of like this, but I'm pretty sure it won't work..

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE
    email='$Email'
    AND date='$Date_Today
    || $Date_Yesterday
    || $Date_TwoDaysAgo
    || $Date_ThreeDaysAgo
    || $Date_FourDaysAgo
    || $Date_FiveDaysAgo
    || $Date_SixDaysAgo
    || $Date_SevenDaysAgo'");
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use parentheses to group the OR statements.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE email='$Email' AND (date='$Date_Today' OR date='$Date_Yesterday' OR date='$Date_TwoDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_ThreeDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_FourDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_FiveDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_SixDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_SevenDaysAgo')");
```

You can also use IN

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE email='$Email' AND date IN ('$Date_Today','$Date_Yesterday','$Date_TwoDaysAgo','$Date_ThreeDaysAgo','$Date_FourDaysAgo','$Date_FiveDaysAgo','$Date_SixDaysAgo','$Date_SevenDaysAgo')");
```

Answer (score 10):

Use brackets:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE email='$Email' AND 
    (date='$Date_Today' 
     OR date='$Date_Yesterday' 
     OR date='$Date_TwoDaysAgo' 
     OR date='$Date_ThreeDaysAgo' 
     OR date='$Date_FourDaysAgo' 
     OR date='$Date_FiveDaysAgo' 
     OR date='$Date_SixDaysAgo' 
     OR date='$Date_SevenDaysAgo'
    )
");
```

But you should alsos have a look at the `IN` operator. So you can say ´date IN ('$date1','$date2',...)`

But if you have always a set of consecutive days why don't you do the following for the date part

```
date <= $Date_Today AND date >= $Date_SevenDaysAgo
```

Comment: Or possibly use the BETWEEN operator.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is about the [operator precedences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) in mysql and [Alex has shown you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8604409/4833) how to "override" the precedence with parentheses.

But on a side note, if your column `date` is of the type [`Date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) you can use [MySQL's date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to fetch the records of the last seven days, like e.g.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Drinks
WHERE
  email='$Email'
  AND date >= Now()-Interval 7 day
```

(or maybe Curdate() instead of Now())

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your AND logic in parenthesis, like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE email='$Email' AND (date='$Date_Today' OR date='$Date_Yesterday' OR date='$Date_TwoDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_ThreeDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_FourDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_FiveDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_SixDaysAgo' OR date='$Date_SevenDaysAgo')");
```

Answer (score -4):

try this

```
mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM Drinks WHERE
    email='$Email'
    AND date='$Date_Today'
    OR date='$Date_Yesterday', '$Date_TwoDaysAgo', '$Date_ThreeDaysAgo', '$Date_FourDaysAgo', '$Date_FiveDaysAgo', '$Date_SixDaysAgo', '$Date_SevenDaysAgo'"     
   );
```

my be like this

```
 OR date='$Date_Yesterday' oR '$Date_TwoDaysAgo'.........
```

Comment: Have you considered deleting this answer? You would get back your lost reputation.