# CodeIgniter Active Record - Group OR statements

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my problem: [MySQL "Or" Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604380/mysql-or-condition)

The solution is to group the OR statements, but i'm using CodeIgniters Active Record. Is there a way to group OR statements using Active Record? Or do I have to write the query myself?

I'm using `$this->db->where()` with `$this->db->or_where()`

It writes the query like this:

`WHERE title = 'foobar' AND category = 2 OR category = 3`

but what I need is:

`WHERE title = 'foobar' AND (category = 2 OR category = 3)`

I can't do this:

```
$this->db->where("title = 'foobar' AND (category = 2 OR category = 3)");
```

because i'm adding ORs using a foreach loop

Comment: practically speaking this wont fetch any rows since it will become either `1 AND 0`  **OR**  `0 AND 1` = `FALSE` condition every time.

Comment: @karanthakkar that was just an example to get an idea, but you're right lol

Comment: can you post the foreach logic. you can use `where_in` if its an array instead of using foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually as stated [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html):

> Custom string: You can write your own clauses manually:
>
> $where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
>
> $this->db->where($where);

As for your question:

```
$this->db->where("category = 1 AND (category = 2 OR category = 3)");
```

In **3.0-dev**:

```
$this->db->select()
->group_start()
->or_like([ 'category' => 2, 'category' => 3 ])
->group_end()                
->where([ 'category' => 1 ]);
```

### update

See the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter) if you're using CI 2.2. <s>Choose an answer other than the accepted</s>.

Or simply try [this](https://eval.in/211243):

```
$categories = array(2, 3);

array_walk($categories, function(&$cat) { $cat = 'category = ' . $cat; });

$catstring  = implode(" OR ", $categories);
$where      = "category = 1 AND ($catstring)";
// => category = 1 AND (category = 2 OR category = 3)

$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: I'm adding the ORs with a foreach loop so that won't work. The 3.0 dev part looks like exactly what I need but I'm using version 2.2

Comment: The accepted answer for the link you posted looks like a good solution but why does it have 8 downvotes?

Comment: @sol , majidarif. there is a built in function in CI as i mentioned.

Comment: @sol the downvotes seems to suggest that you loose the string validation but the documentation says: where() `All values passed to this function are escaped automatically, producing safer queries.`

Comment: So it's a good way to do it right? But you wrote "Choose an answer other than the accepted"

Comment: @sol Based on the documentation it should be safe. So you can disregard my note on choosing another answer than the accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you can't manipulate ground condition query using DB active record methods (where, or_where) , i would recommond to pass as sting in `where()` method

```
$this->db->where("category = 1 AND (category = 2 OR category = 3)");
```

Comment: I can't do that since i'm using a foreach loop (updated my question)

Answer (score 0):

In the Code Igniter  Version 3.0-dev you can add groups in any query using `group_start` and `group_end` :

```
$this->db->select('col1, col2')
->where("category = 1")
->group_start()
->where("category = 2")
->or_where("category = 3")
->group_end();
```

Produces:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM `table_name`
WHERE category = 1 AND (category = 2 OR category = 3);
```

Comment: I'm using version 2.2

Answer (score 0):

as OP mentioned you are generating **OR** using foreach `(array)`
you can simply use

```
    $cat_array=array(2,3,4,5,6,7);
    $this->db->select('col1, col2')->from('table')->where("col1",1)->where_in('col2', $cat_array);
```

will generate

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2` FROM (`table`) WHERE `col1` = 1 AND `col2` IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: The OP's question seems to be misleading and the query he is trying to build is wrong. If that is the case then this is the best answer.

Comment: @majidarif yes may be question is quite misleading though :)