# Is there a way to write combine or mysql statement with codeigniter ivr

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any way to write ivr for the following statement with codeigniter

```
SELECT customer_id, last_name, first_name
FROM customers
WHERE (last_name = 'Johnson' 
OR (last_name = 'Anderson' AND state = 'California') 
OR (last_name = 'Smith' AND status = 'Active' AND state = 'Florida');
```

Coule someone please help me on it ?

Comment: possible only in **codeigniter dev 3.0** in older version use where part as string  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624535/codeigniter-active-record-group-or-statements?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); is not work? im rare using query builder, main using AR class.